# Is there any good documentation for using RDF Annotation with MarkLogic?

Tags: rdf, marklogic

MarkLogic documentation announces annotation and adding metadata to RDF, however I could not find any details. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Improved grammar and clarified question.

Answer (score 4):

In MarkLogic, triples can either annotate documents in a similar style to RDFa, or may be persisted in specific triplestore xml documents.

The [Uses for Triples in XML Documents](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/embedded#id_pgfId-917086) section of the Semantics Developer’s Guide show an example of how a triplestore document and the triple itself can be annotated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sem:triples xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
  <source>AP Newswire</source>
  <sem:triple date="1972-02-21" confidence="100">
    <sem:subject>http://example.org/news/Nixon</sem:subject>
    <sem:predicate>http://example.org/wentTo</sem:predicate>
    <sem:object>China</sem:object>
  </sem:triple>
</sem:triples>
```

In this case, the triplestore document has been annotated to show its source (AP Newswire), and the triple itself has been anotated with the date and our confidence of this fact.

The following query is then used to answer the question:

Which countries did Nixon visit?

- before 1974?
- only show me answers where I have at least 80% confidence
- and the source is AP Newswire OR BBC

..

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
sem:sparql ('
  SELECT ?country
  WHERE {
    <http://example.org/news/Nixon> <http://example.org/wentTo> ?country
  }',
  (),
  (),
  cts:and-query( (
    cts:path-range-query( "//sem:triple/@confidence", ">", 80) ,
    cts:path-range-query( "//sem:triple/@date", "<",xs:date("1974-01-01") ),
    cts:or-query( (
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("source"), "AP Newswire" ),
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("source"), "BBC" )
    ) )
  ) )
)
```

Hope that helps!
Ed

Comment: Thanks Ed! Do I understand correction that sem:store is any sem:triples, that can be within other documents just as well - as long as I provide a list in the last parameter? Does it scale well - meaning if I have a lot of small stores?

Comment: Hi Alex, as long as you're using indexes to generate the sem:store query results, it should scale well; irrespective of the size of the documents.